# How to make two column flex divs align to the bottom of a website

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two divs which need to be aligned next to each other, but also grow to fit the website (downwards) [the two divs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEr5p.png)

I would like the divs to go all the way to the bottom / fit the content.

I can't seem to figure it out and have resulted in stacking them instead of using a column, which looks good on a smaller display but feels weird on a desktop.

Hopefully, someone can help.

Cheers.

```css
/* rough translation of the css (but you get the gist) */
:root {
    —tds-size—3x: 24px;
    —tds-gutter-negative: calc(24px * - 1);
    —tds-size—2x: 16px;
    —tds-card—border-radius: 8px;
    —ids-flex-nm: 1;
}
.tds-flex-gutters {
    -webkit-margin-before: var(--tds-gutter--negative);
    margin-block-start: var(--tds-gutter--negative);
    -webkit-margin-after: var(--tds-size--3x);
    margin-block-end: var(--tds-size--3x);
    -webkit-margin-start: var(--tds-gutter--negative);
    margin-inline-start: var(--tds-gutter--negative);
}
@media (min-width: 600px) {
    .tds-flex {
        flex-flow: row wrap;
    }
}
.tds-flex {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.my-card[_ngcontent-ylf-c110] {
    margin-left: 35px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #fff;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 8%);
    flex: var(--tds-flex-nm);
}
.tds-card {
    padding: var(--tds-size--2x);
    border-radius: var(--tds-card--border-radius);
}
```

```html
<div _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-flex tds-flex-gutters" style="margin-top: 15px;">
    <div _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-card tds-card--dense my-card ng-star-inserted" style="height: fit-content;">
        <span _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="my-card-label">
            News & Announcements
        </span>
        <div _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-card-body my-card-content-small" style="margin: 15px;">
            <ul _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-list">
                <li _ngcontent-ylf-c110="">
                    <h6 _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                        NEWS_TITLE
                    </h6>
                    NEWS_BODY
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-card tds-card--dense my-card" style="height: fit-content;">
        <span _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="my-card-label">
            Changelog
        </span>
        <div _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-card-body my-card-content-small" style="margin: 15px;">
            <ul _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" class="tds-list">
                <li _ngcontent-ylf-c110="">
                    <h6 _ngcontent-ylf-c110="" style="padding-top: 0px;">
                        CHANGELOG_TITLE
                    </h6>
                    CHANGELOG_BODY
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you want them to take full height then set height to 100vh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using [`CSS GRID`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout), we can do this more easily.

by using this CSS property `grid-template-columns`

> documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-columns

also set the height of the parent element to `100vh`

> `100vh` means the height of the device, 
>  and for deleting the bug of scroll-bar appears we will use:
>
>  1. `margin: 0;` to the body element
>
>  2. `box-sizing: border-box;` to all elements

[image]

**this is an example code**

```css
* {
    /* solve the bug of scrollbar be visible */
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
    /* the most important line here */
    display: grid;
    /* 100vh is the height of the device */
    height: 100vh;
    /* another not important for the functionality, only visually css */
    padding: 1rem;
    gap: 1rem;
}

.card {
    /* debugging border, delete it */
    outline: 1px solid red;
    /* centering */
    display: grid;
    place-items: center;
}


/* responsive desktop*/

@media (min-width: 600px) {
    #container {
        /* the css property for pc version */
        grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    }
}
```

```html
<body style="margin: 0;">
    <div id="container">
        <!-- 1 -->
        <div class="card">
            <span>card n1</span>
        </div>

        <!-- 2 -->
        <div class="card">
            <span>card n2</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```